# Queues working with Azure Storage (Classic) but not with modern

Tags: azure, azure-queues

Doing some work with Azure and queues, and I can get it to work with a classic storage account, but not the standard (newer) storage account.

### "Modern" Azure storage account

[image]

### Classic Storage Account

[image]

If I run this code against each of them...:

```
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
var documentProcessQueue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("documentprocessrequest");
documentProcessQueue.CreateIfNotExists();
```

...It works for Classic, but with "modern" I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
> 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in
> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote name could not be resolved:
> 'xxxxxxdocstest.queue.core.windows.net'

**What am I missing? Am I doing something wrong, or does queues simply not work with "moderns" storage accounts (sounds unlikely)?**

I am using the latest version of the Azure SDK. I have tested the connectionstrings to the storage accounts with other things, like uploading a blog, and they do work.

### EDIT:

I created a "modern" Azure Storage account like the below screenshot (and tested with this one, same error) - and I changed the first image to reflect this account.

[image]

Comment: Is the 1st screenshot (modern one) is that of the storage account you're using? I was inclined to say that the Performance tier of the storage account is `Blob Storage` but it shows `Standard` so the queues should work.

Comment: Is this a Premium Storage account?

Comment: It is not premium, no. Just a regular Bizspark account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're getting this error is because you created a `Blob Storage` kind of storage account which only supports blobs. Please see this link to learn more about account kinds: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/.

At this moment, it is not possible to convert this account into a regular (standard) storage account. Thus you would need to create a new storage account and transfer any blobs that you may have in this account to a newer account.

When you create the new storage account, please ensure that the redundancy type of that account is not `ZRS` or `Premium LRS` as storage accounts with these redundancy type only support blobs again.